# How to delete the child from the root in html javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Following is the code for adding the circular shape on the page for number for number of times? This is done by using createElementNS() and appendChild() functions. Now how to delete or remove this child from the root? Which function should we use ?

```
function add(){
        flag=0;
        var C=document.createElementNS(xmlns,"circle") 
        var stroke=Color()
        var rad=6
        var Attr={
            r:rad,
            cx:200, 
            cy:200,
            "fill": Color(),
            "fill-opacity":.75,
            "stroke": stroke,
            "stroke-opacity":.5,
            "id":stroke,
            "stroke-width":10+(30-rad)
        }
        assignAttr(C,Attr)
        Root.appendChild(C)
    }
```

Comment: Ever tried `Root.removeChild(C);` ...?

Comment: Yes i tried that but i can't access 'C' in other function.

Comment: Then find this C, e.g. using `var c = Root.lastChild;`

Comment: thanks! And can you tell how to traverse the whole tree from first child to last child ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the element you want to remove, you can get the parent node and remove the element from it using [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('dummy');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```